# Is Mono's share().block() non-blocking?

Tags: jackson, spring-webflux

I am in the middle of learning Spring WebFlux. I am using a REST call using below code to parse the response:

```
private void parseJsonResponse(String folderId) throws IOException {
    Mono<ObjectNode> theresponseMono = webClient.get()
            .uri("/some/uri")
            .retrieve().bodyToMono(ObjectNode.class);
    ObjectNode node = new ObjectMapper().disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
            .readValue(theresponseMono.share().block().toString(), ObjectNode.class);
   //handle node object here.....
}
```

**Question:** Is `theresponseMono.share().block()` non-blocking here? If not, what can be done to make is completely non-blocking. I am looking for the relevant documentation on this as I want to learn it and not just looking for a `yes or no`. To summarize, I need to retrieve `theresponseMono` as non-blocking. Any guidance or any official documentation/link on this please? Thanks.

EDIT:
This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
Mono<ObjectNode> theresponseMono = webClient.get()
                .uri("/some/uri")
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(ObjectNode.class).flatMap(node -> {
                    if (node.get("list").get("entries").isArray()) {

                        for (JsonNode jsonNode : node.get("list").get("entries")) {
                            System.out.println(jsonNode);
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Somehow I am not able to map using flatMap. What is missing here?

Comment: as an aside, the code you've shared seems redundant. The response is being unmarshalled to a `ObjectNode`, which then gets converted to a `String` and then unmarshalled again into a `ObjectNode`.

Answer (score 1):

No since here you are blocking it. Right way would be to do

```
private Mono<ObjectNode> parseJsonResponse(String folderId) {
    return  webClient.get()
            .uri("/some/rui")
            .retrieve().bodyToMono(ObjectNode.class)
            .flatMap(node-> {
                   // do your logic here
             })
}
```

I would say everything what is in mono/flux must stay in mono/flux :) Anytime you call block its blocking your thread.

Comment: How do I iterate the node’s key value pair?

Comment: I updated the question with EDIT secion.